# PyCharm: Excluding a single file from autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm, gruntjs

So, at my job we have grunt.js running to compile all of our js into a single file.  This is great little feature of grunt.js (with grunt:requirejs/growl) BUT its causing a problem.  PyCharm will frequently freeze for 3 - 10 seconds.

If i disable grunt then the freezing wont happen (since there is no 65 KLOC js file).  The files that are combined are being parsed (is what i have narrowed it down to) for autocomplete.  How would i remove a single file?  I could, potentially create a folder for the combined file, but i really do not want too...

---

Edit:  Better engrish...
Not "remove" a single file, but "exclude" a single file (sorry, brain.speed > finger.speed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer, the obvious one, is that the file system, with grunts, need to have the automagic combined files in their own directory.  Then that directory can be excluded.  (Right click, toward the bottom).

Since i did that, my pycharm has yet to freeze.

Comment: I did wish that i did not have to do this, but its as good as it gets sometimes.